# Leyendo un archivo. ¿Cuál es el significado de esta línea de código en Perl?

Tags: linux, funciones, perl

Soy nueva en Perl. Acabo de iniciar hoy con esto y estoy aprendiendo a manipular ficheros.

Conozco el funcionamiento de la estructura `while` y lo he usado en otros lenguajes. Lo que no comprendo es "`($linea=<INPUT>)`"

¿Lo que está entre estos símbolos "`<>`" hace referencia a una "etiqueta" o qué significa?

Aquí está el código:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Ingreso el nombre del fichero que quiero abrir
print "Nombre del fichero:";
$fichero=<STDIN>;

chop($fichero);

open (INPUT,"$fichero") || die "ERROR: No es posible abrir $fichero\n";

while ($linea=<INPUT>) {
    print $linea;
}

close (INPUT);
```

Comment: ROWE, bienvenido  al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento 

básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con 

respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, 

esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto 

**es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Lo que esta entre estos simbolos "`<INPUT>`" hace referencia a una
>   "etiqueta" o qué significa?

Se refiere al contenido del archivo que abriste mediante:

```
open (INPUT,"$fichero")
```

El operador usado `<>`, es también llamado [**operador diamante**](https://perlmaven.com/the-diamond-operator),  el cual se parece al operador readline, ejemplo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
    print $line;
}
```

---

En el caso que comentas `($linea=<INPUT>)`, el contenido de la linea obtenida del archivo lo agrega a la variable `$linea` , e imprime el valor :

```
while ($linea=<INPUT>) {
  print $linea;
}
```

Lo recomendable es usar esta forma para imprimir el valor de cada linea obtenida del archivo:

```
while (<INPUT>) {
   print "$_";
}
```

---

Código con explicación:

```
#Ingreso el nombre del fichero que quiero abrir
print "Nombre del fichero:";
$fichero=<STDIN>;  #Obtiene nombre del archivo a partir de que el usuario lo teclea. 

chop($fichero); #Eliminar caracter retorno de carro (carriage return).

#Abre archivo, en caso de no realizarlo envía el mensaje "ERROR: No es posible abrir $fichero\n".
open (INPUT,"$fichero") || die "ERROR: No es posible abrir $fichero\n";

#Si pudo abrir el archivo imprime cada linea del mismo.
while ($linea=<INPUT>) {
  print $linea;
}

close (INPUT); #Cierra archivo.
```

Comment: Conviene señalar que no se recomienda abrir ficheros usando `open(FH, "<", "input.txt")`, sino `open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")` (o `open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "input.txt")`). (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, decirte que se escribe Perl, no PERL. Tienes más información en la página de Perl en la Wikipedia española.

El operador diamante (<>) hace lo mismo que la función readline(), solo que hay que escribir menos. Tienes más información en tu ordenador, ejecutando el comando **perldoc -f readline** .